# Change character in list Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, flask, arguments

so here is my relativly simple code:

```
@app.route("/[<string:pfade>]")
def testaufruf(pfade):

   s=list(pfade)

   part = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x=="$"]

   print(part)

   s[part]="\\"

   print(part)
```

My problem is I want to pass something like `127.0.0.1:5000/[Test$path1]`

now I take this `Test$path1` make it an list and want to replace every `$` with an `\`

These lines work:

```
s=list(pfade)

part = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x=="$"]

print(part)
```

They return me the place where the `$` is located but the second part to replace the `$` does not work. I did search a lot but couldnt find a solution to this problem.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings have a `replace` method:

```
part = pfade.replace('$', '\\')
```

Note the `\` is repeated for escaping.

Comment: Thats even easier, thanks a lot! Dont need a list anymore

Answer (score 1):

this line is gonna return a list of integers

```
part = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x=="$"]
```

and you're simply trying to index `s` with a list, you're facing the following error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.
```

to solve this:

```
parts = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x=="$"]
for part in parts:
    s[part] = '\\'

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it was a pretty simple fix:

instead of using `part = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x=="$"]`

I just used: `part = s.index("$", 0)`

than `s[part] = "\\"` replaces the `$` with `"\"`

Comment: note that this is not gonna work if you have more than one index with ```$```